# slide down with toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to toggle my div with anchor tag but code is not working. please let me know where i have mistake in code.

```
    jquery code
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#status_1').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of link tag
        $(this).parent().next('.hide-show').slideToggle();
    });
});



  html code

    <a href="#" id="status_1" class="bitcon"></a>


    <div class="hide-show">
            Hellow world
                </div>
Css:

.hide-show{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks All of you Respected fellows my problem is solved...

Answer (score 0):

So, Why are you put parent in it??
This is sibling of anchor my friend

If you want to use parent then

```
$(this).parent().find('.hide-show').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be with part of the code here:
    " $(this).parent().next "

you can try simply:

```
$('.hide-show').slideToggle();
```

This will select your div with the class hide-show and apply .slidetoggle(); to it.

Instead of what you currently have which is looking for the parent of the link  with class status_1 and finding the next link.

Comment: Hey, If this helped you, consider marking it as the right answer, and/or an up vote. Thank you. Glad I could help.

Comment: sir just let me know one more thing.. if i want to use this code to load multiple divs then how i will use this code..

Comment: You can chain selectors in Jquery, so $('.hide-show , .SECOND_DIV, .THIRD_DIV , .FOURTH_DIV').slideToggle();